# distance_of_time_in_words from created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using `distance_of_time_in_words` with rails 4 on created_at attribute but it doesn't works

in my view:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
....
<td><%= distance_of_time_in_words(post.created_at,  post.created_at + 30.days)   %></td>
```

it show always:

```
about 1 month
```

If I use time_ago_in_words it works

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu you can ignore the questions that you do not like, and as you see you're wrong there are people who answered in a more educated  and intelligent mode. please don't reply again. bye

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant to be rude or anything. I'm actually deleting my comment and this kind of things have also happened to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's say `post.created_at` is sept 01.

```
sept 1,  sept 1 + 30 days
```

is about one month. If you always have `post.created_at,  post.created_at + 30.days` then it's always going to return `about one month` because that's the amount of time you're giving it.